# What's the actual URL Rails generated for HTTP Verb PATCH?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack

Please bear with a newbie. I understand how Rails provides simple request with GET for simple URL links like `localhost:3000/rooms/11/listing`. The format is straight forward as stated in the Routes table. However I am confuse when it comes to PATCH, PUT, DELETE & CREATE. For example the output below, with params, was when I clicked SAVE button. My question, what's the actual URL that Rails generated when I clicked that SAVE button?

```
Started PATCH "/rooms/11" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-08-20 05:25:32 +0800
(0.8ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
  ↳ /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
Processing by RoomsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"JHiCJ6HoTsgd8SGgLTFiZ9+J9hS9U8hHGvjKf4Lz3uieQ8OO2eFqFEM/D5xocHp/Nd3eA0az9k+okrmNe65BYg==", "room"=>{"home_type"=>"Apartment", "room_type"=>"Private", "accommodate"=>"3", "bed_room"=>"4", "bath_room"=>"3"}, "commit"=>"Save", "id"=>"11"}
```

I know from console

```
app.room_path(11)
 => "/rooms/11"
```

Is this Rails generated URL `localhost:3000/rooms/11{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"JHiCJ6HoTsgd8SGgLTFiZ9+J9hS9U8hHGvjKf4Lz3uieQ8OO2eFqFEM/D5xocHp/Nd3eA0az9k+okrmNe65BYg==", "room"=>{"home_type"=>"Apartment", "room_type"=>"Private", "accommodate"=>"3", "bed_room"=>"4", "bath_room"=>"3"}, "commit"=>"Save", "id"=>"11"}`?

Comment: If you are using Chrome and want to inspect the request you can open the developer tools, choose the Network tab, and check the box "Preserve log". 

Click on your save button and the request to /rooms/11 will show up on the list with all sorts of useful information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the URL generated by `app.room_path(11)` is `http://localhost:3000/rooms/11`.

PATCH, PUT, DELETE and POST are called HTTP verbs. *CREATE is not an HTTP verb.*

One of these verbs goes along with your request, and Rails Router uses it to route the request to the correct Controller and Action.

Requests can have parameters, likes the one you showed here:
`{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"JHiCJ6HoTsgd8SGgLTFiZ9+J9hS9U8hHGvjKf4Lz3uieQ8OO2eFqFEM/D5xocHp/Nd3eA0az9k+okrmNe65BYg==", "room"=>{"home_type"=>"Apartment", "room_type"=>"Private", "accommodate"=>"3", "bed_room"=>"4", "bath_room"=>"3"}, "commit"=>"Save", "id"=>"11"}`

When you clicked on the Save button your browser requested `http://localhost:3000/rooms/11`  using the HTTP verb POST. The parameters were encoded on the body of the request.

A good place to learn more about this would be the [Rails routing guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Here is the result from `rake routes` command. As you can see, GET, PATCH and PUT share the same generated URL (/rooms/:id, in your example /rooms/11). Since Rails 4.0, PATCH is the default verb to update action. Update action is triggered when you're sending a form to a route.